# How to restrict web server written in golang to allow a particular address instead of a pattern?

Tags: http, go, server, url-pattern

When I use

```
http.HandleFunc("/", serveRest)  //serveRest is the method to handle request
http.ListenAndServe("localhost:4000", nil)
```

It will accept all request starting with `"/"`. How do I restrict it to serve only `"localhost:4000"` instead of every address like `"localhost:4000/*"`?

And can you guys suggest me a good tutorial for Go?

Answer (score 7):

The URL pattern to which you register your handlers is documented in the [`http.ServeMux`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) type:

> Patterns name fixed, rooted paths, like "/favicon.ico", or rooted subtrees, like "/images/" (note the trailing slash). Longer patterns take precedence over shorter ones, so that if there are handlers registered for both "/images/" and "/images/thumbnails/", the latter handler will be called for paths beginning "/images/thumbnails/" and the former will receive requests for any other paths in the "/images/" subtree.
>
> Note that since a pattern ending in a slash names a rooted subtree, the pattern "/" matches all paths not matched by other registered patterns, not just the URL with Path == "/".

So unfortunately there is no pattern which matches only the root (`"/"`).

But you can easily check this in your handler, and do whatever you want to if the request path is not the root:

```
func serveRest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        w.Write([]byte("Not root!"))
        return
    }
    
    w.Write([]byte("Hi, this is the root!"))
}
```

If you want to return `HTTP 404 Not found` error for non-roots:

```
func serveRest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    w.Write([]byte("Hi!"))
}
```

And Go tutorial: https://tour.golang.org/

Also check out the <kbd>[Go](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info)</kbd> tag info here on SO, it has a section **Go Tutorials**.

Comment: Thanks @icza, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out 
https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter

Per its readme:

> Only explicit matches: With other routers, like http.ServeMux, a
>   requested URL path could match multiple patterns. Therefore they have
>   some awkward pattern priority rules, like longest match or first
>   registered, first matched. By design of this router, a request can
>   only match exactly one or no route. As a result, there are also no
>   unintended matches, which makes it great for SEO and improves the user
>   experience.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/user/toddmcleod/playlists) is some good video content to get started in Go.